# Looking for an example of drools bassd rule for sequence of events

Tags: events, sequence, drools, complex-event-processing

I tried a few different formats but I'm interested in finding matches for when event of A follows B and the next set within the sequence doesn't begin until the previous sequence ends

Comment: What do you mean by e1: Event(... -> ...)` - the arrow isn't a valid operator. --- Please explain more clearly why do you want to run a *query* on *events*. How would you know when to run a query which is targeted at one certain event after another event?

Comment: Also,please clarify what you mean by "to query in sequence". Do you mean these three ($e2,$e3,$e4) events in sequence? With nothing in between? Just one triplet or any such triplet?

Comment: Yes - i am trying to run a pattern match for events that occur in a sequence with nothing in between.  So yes, that ($e2, $e3, $e4) happen in sequence.  Also I'd be interested in the sequence within a given time parameter.

Comment: Hmm, sounds like "rule" now - as opposed to "query", which doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Hi, yes you are right - i don't make much sense calling it a query, sorry!  But the sample looks exactly right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A rule like

```
rule x1
when
  $e1 : Event( eventCode == "NMG_ESO 15", text contains "Exception Time")
  $e2 : Event( this after $e1,
               eventCode == "NMG_DET 57", text contains "Exception Time")
then ... end
```

fires when the first `NMG_DET 57` arrives after the `NMG_ESO 15`. It would also fire for the next `NMG_DET 57`. It is now up to you to provide more precise requirements and handle the first match accordingly. Perhaps you'll have to retract `$31`and `$e2` so that the engine is ready to detect another pair, or maybe not.

You can extend this easily to a succession of three events. Again, after the first match you'll have to decide what should happen.

Comment: Hi! New to Drools. Does this require both events (or all three of them) are in KIE Session? Thanks!

Comment: @HasanCanSaral Don't attach questions to old answers, ask a new question with enough details illustrating what you really want to know. -- I'm not sure what you are asking here, mainly because I don't know what you mean by "this".